# Profile issues with google chrome

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, user-profile

I am facing an issue with my automation script.I am logging into a URL in my script.When I do that manually it login normally but when I use automation script it asks for verification code which is available on my mail.

I thought if I will use the chrome default profile for login then this issue should not arise.But it didn't helped me out.

Can anyone suggest any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

As known, Webdriver always starts with fresh, default profile. That is the reason its asking for verification but not same when do manually. To avoid it, you can specify the chrome profile which is used manually to webdriver.

In Java, we can done it by using ChromeOptions and Chrome Profile. In chrome navigate to chrome://version/ It will display profile path and Executable path.

As per my working on this, \Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 3 is displaying when navigate to chrome://version/ in normal chrome. In this profile, i navigated to stackoverflow and saved credentials. So used below code

```
 Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("binary", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\selenium_setups\\poi-3.12\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\murali\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 3");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

//WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/");
```

As per my understanding, i excepted stackoverflow.com page displayed as logged in. but for first time, i am not logged in. so cross checked with chrome://version/ in chrome opened by driver, profile path is displayed as
\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 3\Default . then logged manually in that profile it self, which is opened by webdriver and executed gain by closing it.

Finally, page is displayed as logged in. So it may be in java, i hope it will helps you.

Thank You,
Murali