# Is there any why to get web session which is driven by one time password for browser only

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, session-cookies, webautomation

I'm setting a session with chrome in which is a need to log in the website with username, password and an OTP (one-time-Password) which is sent on the phone. The OTP is for browser only, which means if I enter a username, password and OTP in chrome once, next time it will ask me for username and password only not for OTP. I'm using selenium-python to automate this and selenium always open a new browser Window. How can I overcome this situation?

I tried to save the cookies and then get it to load on the driver but still asking for OTP.

```
# Saved functions are below.

import pickle

# Path = "E:\\Python\\cookies\\cookies.pkl".
def save_cookie(driver, path):
    """
    Save cookies in cookies folder.
    """
    with open(path, 'wb') as filehandler:
        pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), filehandler)

def load_cookie(driver,path):
    """
    Load cookies from the saved folder.
    """
    with open(path, 'rb') as cookiesfile:
        cookies = pickle.load(cookiesfile)
        for cookie in cookies:
            driver.add_cookie(cookie)

# Here is what I'm trying.

from selenium import webdriver
from udf import cookies
import pickle

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://somewebsite.com/')
cookies.save_cookie(driver,'E:\\Python\\cookies\\cookies.pkl')

cookies.load_cookie(driver, 'E:\\Python\\cookies\\cookies.pkl')

driver.refresh()
```

I still need to submit OTP for the Chrome browser.

Comment: every time you create a new instance of Chrome() it uses a fresh browser (with profile and empty cookies/storage)

Comment: you can create profile manually and use it in automation. here is my old post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36275652/profile-issues-with-google-chrome in java but we have to use chromeOptions now instead of DesiredCapabilities.

Comment: @murali can you tell me more about this I'm new to selenium and web automation.

Comment: You need to log in with OTP first and then save your cookies.

Comment: @HarpreetSingh see provided answer

Answer (score 0):

Open chrome browser manually. Navigate to chrome://version/

Note down Profile Path, its profile presently you are using.

In same browser navigate to you application, do login with all required things.

then call this profile in script.

See this how to call in python [How to load default profile in chrome using Python Selenium Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062789/how-to-load-default-profile-in-chrome-using-python-selenium-webdriver)

You have to provide Profile Path here in above link

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Path") #Path to your chrome profile
```

Comment: OP is using `pickle`. Possibly you can add some help handling the cookies as well.

Comment: @DebanjanB Its not doing anything, just added for further code.

Comment: @HarpreetSingh The comment was for muraliselenium :) Anyway if _pickle_ and _cookies_ have no role in your question you should remove those code-lines to make things simpler.

Answer (score 0):

below code worked for me. 
Description: I had created a new profile in Chrome by following steps [chrome://settings/](http://chrome://settings/)> Add and Manage People > Add Person. Then, login to my youtube account in the new profile. Then following code gives me auto logged-in youtube page. Profile Path can be found in [chrome://version/](http://chrome://version/) in Profile Path: key.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\randh\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 2") #Path to your chrome profile which you have created.
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options) #Place webdrivers in Scripts folder of Python(Where Python is installed), so that it can be picked automatically.
driver.get('https://youtube.com')
```

Like or comment...

Comment: If answer works for you you can mark it as accepted one (checkmark to the left of it) Even if answer is your own.